# Set return type optional for mutation in resolver

Tags: nestjs, resolver

In nestjs resolver I have mutation that generates required type how can i set the mutation optional return type?

```
@Mutation(returns => appId)
  async updateAppId(
    @Args('appId') appId: string,
  ) {}
```

generating

```
type Mutation {
  updateAppId(appId: String!): appId!
}
```

How can I set the return type optional?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by declaring the mutation result nullable:

```js
@Mutation(returns => appId, { nullable: true })
```